# Cannot open a connection to SQL localDB

Tags: c#, sql-server, database-connection, sql-server-express, localdb

I'm building a Windows form application using C# and SQL LocalDB 2012 as the database engine. The first time the application starts up, I want to create a new instance of the database server, create a new login and disable the default Windows login to prevent users for accessing the row database.
First, I try a Connection.Open() to see if the instance and new login work. If I get an exception, I call two procedures to create the new instance and login.

I'm running through a weird situation. After creating the new instance, creating the new login and disabling the default Windows login, SqlConnection.Open() throws an exception. The weird thing is that if I do one of two things, the connection opens normally without an exception:

1- If I run the code in debug mode step by step, it will work without an exception. If I run the same code normally by pressing the "Start" button, it throws an exception.

2- If I comment out the initial code where I try a Connection.Open() to see if the instance and login have already been created - if I comment out that Conneciton.Open() and force the code to create a new instance and login, no exception is thrown.

Here is my code. I removed the irrelevant parts.

```
// The below throws an exception
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Windows;

    class Program
    {

    const string connectionString = @"Data Source=(localdb)\MyInstance;User Id=NewLogin;Password=test123;";
    const string TestConnectionString = @"Data Source=(localdb)\MyInstance;Integrated Security=true;";
    const string DBInstanceName = "MyInstance";
    // To replicate, replace 'Ahmad-PC\Ahmad' with your Windows login
    const string changeDBUserSQL =
    @" IF  EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.server_principals WHERE name = N'NewLogin')" +
    @" DROP LOGIN[NewLogin]" +
    @" CREATE LOGIN NewLogin" +
    @" WITH PASSWORD = 'test123';" +
    @" CREATE USER NewUser FOR LOGIN NewLogin;  " +
    @" EXEC master..sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame = N'NewLogin', @rolename = N'sysadmin' " +
    @" IF  EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.server_principals WHERE name = N'Ahmad-PC\Ahmad')" +
    @" EXEC master..sp_dropsrvrolemember @loginame = N'Ahmad-PC\Ahmad', @rolename = N'sysadmin' ";


    static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            startup();
        }
        static void startup()
        {
            
            SqlConnection testCon = new SqlConnection();
            bool NamedInstanceExists = false;
            try
            {
                testCon.ConnectionString = connectionString;
                testCon.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                NamedInstanceExists = false;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (testCon.State == ConnectionState.Open) testCon.Close();
                testCon.Dispose();
            }

            if (!NamedInstanceExists)
            {
                CreateNamedDBInstance();
                CreateNewDBUser();
            }

            SqlConnection conn2;
            conn2 = new SqlConnection();
            conn2.ConnectionString = connectionString;
            try
            {
                // An exception is thrown here
                conn2.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    public static void CreateNamedDBInstance()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.FileName = "sqllocaldb.exe";
        startInfo.Arguments = "create " + DBInstanceName;
        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        try
        {
            process.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
        while (!process.HasExited) ;
    }

    public static void CreateNewDBUser()
    {
        SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection(TestConnectionString);
        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(changeDBUserSQL, myConn);
        try
        {
            myConn.Open();
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (myConn.State == ConnectionState.Open) myConn.Close();
            myCommand.Dispose();
            myConn.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

The thrown exception is

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. The specified LocalDB instance does not exist.

**EDIT 1, edited the above code, it is now reproducible**
If you do the following changes to the code, it will run to the end without exceptions:
Line 32, make it

```
            bool NamedInstanceExists = false;
```

Comment out line 36:

```
//                testCon.Open();
```

Comment: It the database (mdf file) already attached to a server?  LocalDb (attach file) should only be used when the database is not attached to a server, and when the mdf file is not on a remote machine.  When a mdf file is attached to a server the server owns the file and usually will not allow other users permission to read the file.  Also when mdf file is on a remote machine you may not have the credentials to access the file.

Comment: @Sinatr, the code now is reproducible.

Comment: @jdweng, I'm getting this problem before even creating the database. There is no mdf file yet. I'm trying to create a named instance of SQLServer and the create a new login.

Comment: Do not put the cart before the horse.  You cannot connect to a database that doesn't exist.  So either run your SQL Query from SQL Server Management Studio to create the database or from VS add a datasource before running code.

Comment: @jdweng, first I'm not connecting to a database. If you look at the connection string, it just references the server instance, no "initial catalog". Second, how else can I grammatically check whether the named instance have already been created or not?

Comment: The is why I also said you can create the datasource manually in VS through menu.